# How to calculate the total error of a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, error

I know that my question sounds really simple, but honestly I don't know how to calculate it. The error = expected output- estimated output, but what does total error mean? Is it the sum of the error for all training samples? or the sum of the errors for all the neurons at the output layer??

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I used MSE for error calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total error it's just information for you or for some heuristic algorithms where you need just compare current iteration error with error from previous epoch. So you can compute error as you wish.

But before making it you need to think that you calculate it in the right way. For example, if you use error function as

$E = target - output$

and for example you have this data

$target = [1, 0, 1]$

$output = [0, 1, 1]$

Error you will get:

$E = [1, 0, 1] - [0, 1, 1] = [1, -1, 0]$

And if you try calculate the mean, you'll get this result:

$mean = \frac{1 + (-1) + 0}{3} = 0$

So your error is $0$. It's wrong (as solution you can use absolute value of error and then take a mean). But in real algorithm you will probably use cross entropy or square error there no this problem. Simple difference you will use only for simple algorithms like Perceptron.

Also if you use square error in huge data you can get big output error, maybe $10000$ or $100000$ and after n-th iteration you error will get something like $50$ error and your graph will be not really informative, because result function will look like a step function.

Comment: In my code I used MSE for error calculations, not the (target-output) I just mentioned it as an example. So I can say that the total network error is the sum of the errors per epoch? What should I do in the case of huge data to avoid the problem you stated?

Comment: Get a mean of your error. If you have $n$ input units you need divide your square error by $n$.